# How to run React-Native app on expo after using react-native init?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am a beginner in concerns of React Native.
I set up a react-native project via

`react-native init projectname`

I got this working on my android studio emulator. Now I want to run it inside my Expo-App. But always when I run `npm start` inside my app project folder it loads just this: [CMD Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O2fE.png)

How can I manage to open my project inside the Expo-App? (Is it even possible?)

Best Whishes
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no tools to convert a "vanilla" react-native project to Expo.

According to the [docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq.html#how-do-i-get-my-existing-react):

> Right now, the easiest way to do this is to use expo init (with Expo
>   CLI) to make a new project, and then copy over all your JavaScript
>   source code from your existing project, and then yarn adding the
>   library dependencies you have.